# For loop divide numbers

Tags: c++, for-loop, divide

I'm an amateur when it comes to C++ but I've already received a task which is over my knowledge.

Task is to enter numbers n,m. Programme must take it as an interval, in which it checks if there is any number which is a sum of numbers with the same exponent.

**EDIT:(18.10.15)** 
Turns out I didn't understood my task correctly. Here it is:

"User enter two numbers. Programme takes it as the interval in which it checks all the numbers. If there's a number in interval which all digit's sum of SAME exponent is that number, then programme shows it."

For example, I enter 100 and 200. In this interval there's 153.
153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 (1+125+27)
Programme shows 153.

```
cin >> n;
cin >> m;
    for (int i=n; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for (int k=n; k<=i; k++)
        {
                a = n % 10; //for example, I enter 153, then a=3
                f = n /= 10; //f=15
                b = f % 10;  //b=5
                f = f /= 10; //f=1
                c = f % 10; //c=1
                f = f /= 10;
                d = f % 10;

                for (int j=1; j<=5; j++)
                {
                    a = a * a;
                    b = b * b;
                    c = c * c;
                    d = d * d;
                    if (a + b + c + d == n)
                    {
                        cout << n << endl;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look up the `pow` function to calculate exponent values.

Comment: Is the number of terms and the exponent inputs to the program or do you need to search for those too?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Any number in any range can be seen as a sum of numbers with the same exponent. And there are precisely infinite versions of these exponents.

Comment: Matthew, is this the complete task? It smells like a homework problem but it seems you might be leaving out some info. For one thing, does every number need to be unique? And what do you need the program to return?

Answer (score 1):

> Task is to enter numbers n,m. Programme must take it as an interval, in which it checks if there is any number which is a sum of numbers with the same exponent.

Assuming the range is given as `[n, m)`, then here's your program:

```
return (n != m);
```

Any number can be seen as a sum of numbers with the same exponent. For example:

```
0 = 0 ^ 3 + 0 ^ 3 + 0 ^ 3
1 = 1 ^ 3 + 0 ^ 3
2 = 1 ^ 3 + 1 ^ 3
3 = 1 ^ 3 + 1 ^ 3 + 1 ^ 3
```

and so on. This is true even for negative numbers.

So in any non-empty range there exists at least 1 such number.

Answer (score 0):

"All I know is how to get the programm to check each number separately"
"Programme must not use arrays."

```
    for (int i = n; i <= m; i++) {
        ...
        int x = (int)Math.log10(i);
        int rest = i;
        for (int p = x; p>=0; p--) {
            int digit = rest / (int)Math.pow(10,p);
            rest = i % (int)Math.pow(10,p);

            //3802 = 3*10^3 + 8*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 2*10^0 
        }
    }

    ...
```

Sorry, is Java no C++

Comment: "checks if there is any number which is a sum of numbers with the same exponent". In your example `3*10^3 + 8*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 2*10^0 ` they don't have the same exponents. :)

Comment: OP phrased his question really poorly, but I do think he wanted all the exponents to match.

Comment: That's possible, but I have followed the statement ;-)
"All I know is how to get the programm to check each number separately" "Programme must not use arrays."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I answer so late and that I phrased my question poorly - English isn't my native language.

But turns out I didn't understood my task correctly. Here it is:

"User enter two numbers. Programme takes it as the interval in which it checks all the numbers. If there's a number in interval which all digit's sum of SAME exponent is that number, then programme shows it."

For example, I enter 100 and 200. In this interval there's 153.
153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 (1+125+27)
Programme shows 153.

```
cin >> n;
cin >> m;
    for (int i=n; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for (int k=n; k<=i; k++)
        {
                a = n % 10; //for example, I enter 153, then a=3
                f = n /= 10; //f=15
                b = f % 10;  //b=5
                f = f /= 10; //f=1
                c = f % 10; //c=1
                f = f /= 10;
                d = f % 10;

                for (int j=1; j<=5; j++)
                {
                    a = a * a;
                    b = b * b;
                    c = c * c;
                    d = d * d;
                    if (a + b + c + d == n)
                    {
                        cout << n << endl;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```